# Merge values with corresponding IDs r

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID1 Value1  ID2 Value2  ID3 Value3
1   566771  1   566771  1   575619
2   660608  2   660608  3   666272
3   362294  4   362294  4   367169
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ID1 Value1 Value2 Value3
```

How can I merge it so that it gets the values that correspond with the ID that matches ID1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
names(df)[seq(1, ncol(df), by=2)] <- "ID"
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all.x=TRUE), lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by=2), function(x) df[x:(x+1)]))
#   ID Value1 Value2 Value3
# 1  1 566771 566771 575619
# 2  2 660608 660608     NA
# 3  3 362294     NA 666272
```